# How do you test that an Titanium Alloy migration will work?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I'm about to release an app update of an iPhone app that I've written in Titanium Alloy. I've added a new column to the database, so I've written a migration for it. The upwards migration is simple enough, just altering the table to add a new column. However, the downwards migration has be a little worried as it involved creating a temporary database, storing the data I need, and then dropping the existing data base and creating a new one with the stored data, in order to keep remove column.

How do I test that this code is correct and will work?

Here are my migrations:

```
migration.up = function(migrator) {
    migrator.db.execute('ALTER TABLE ' + migrator.table + ' ADD COLUMN is_sample BOOLEAN;');
};

migration.down = function(migrator) {
    var db = migrator.db;
    var table = migrator.table;
    db.execute('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE beers_backup(alloy_id,name,brewery,rating,percent,establishment,location,notes,date,date_string,beer_image,latitude,longitude,favourite);');
    db.execute('INSERT INTO beers_backup SELECT alloy_id,name,brewery,rating,percent,establishment,location,notes,date,date_string,beer_image,latitude,longitude,favourite FROM ' + table + ';');
    migrator.dropTable();
    migrator.createTable({
        columns: {
            "name": "text",
            "brewery": "text",
            "rating": "integer",
            "percent": "integer",
            "establishment": "text",
            "location": "text",
            "notes": "text",
            "date": "text",
            "date_string": "text",
            "beer_image": "text",
            "latitude": "integer",
            "longitude": "integer",
            "favourite": "boolean"
        },
    });
    db.execute('INSERT INTO ' + table + ' SELECT alloy_id,name,brewery,rating,percent,establishment,location,notes,date,date_string,beer_image,latitude,longitude,favourite FROM beers_backup;');
    db.execute('DROP TABLE beers_backup;');
};
```

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have the previous app build available?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I could roll back the app using version control and create a build, if that's what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine as long as your first migration file (the one you created when you created the model) matches up with the downward migration here.

Like this:

```
migration.up = function(migrator){
 migrator.createTable({
  columns: {
   "name": "text",
   "brewery": "text",
   "rating": "integer",
   "percent": "integer",
   "establishment": "text",
   "location": "text",
   "notes": "text",
   "date": "text",
   "date_string": "text",
   "beer_image": "text",
   "latitude": "integer",
   "longitude": "integer",
   "favourite": "boolean"
  }
});
};

migration.down = function(migrator) {
 migrator.droptTable();
};
```

This migration file has to have a timestamp that is less than the one you listed in the original question.